# After installing NVIDIA all fonts are bold

Tags: firefox, nvidia-graphics-card

I decided to do a very stupid thing - I installed NVIDIA updates. First, my computer was completelly out of order, but after restoring it, it can be used at least. But some problems still remained, and one of them is the fact, that I have all text in my browser (mozzila firefox) bold.

Here are three screenshots:

1. [My stackoverflow profile.](http://u8.8u.cz/images/allbold.png)
2. [Google search results.](http://u8.8u.cz/images/allbold2.png)
3. [Proof that it is rather a browser bug.](http://u8.8u.cz/images/allbold3.png)

PS.: Editors, pleave leave images as links. Thumbnails of this images will be useless, so its a waste of space and bandwidth.

Comment: I can't see the pictures right now because it's blocked and the network admin already monitors me enough for past incidents so the only thing I can recommend is a re-install of firefox. It sounds like a stupid answer to your problem at first but due to the update firefox might be interpreting something things differently.  Also Nvidia updates aren't stupid. They can increase performance by quite a bit.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid reinstalling anything - I have lots of stuf in my firefox. Meanwhile, I found out that my problem may be a missing font problem - though I have no idea, what was nvidia changing within fonts folder.
 And about that NVIDIA updates - they increased my rage by 100%. Even before my PC went down, I had problems even installing them, but this is already out of topic. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You don't need a full reinstall. While I don't personally use Firefox I'm very sure you can uninstall and reinstall without uninstalling cookies bookmarks ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my problem was fixed by reinstalling the system fonts. I downloaded [this torrent](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/5259717/Windows_7_Original_Fonts) and I've unpacked its contents to `C:\Windows\Fonts`.
It seems that Firefox used Arial Bold, when normal Arial was not found.

Comment: for situations like this i always have a backup of fonts on a pendrive. maybe you should consider it to avoid future problems.

Comment: Good point - I actually already did this, having the archive from torrent downloaded on external HDD.